# Analysis of running time on recursive function

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I'm struggling with finding out the operation time of when n is 10,000 in this recursive function:

```
def fib3(n):
    if n<3:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-3)
```

I understand in loops it is straightforward to say what the running time is - it is the number of loops, but how do we do this in recursion?

Comment: "in loops it is straightforward to say what the running time is - it is the number of loops" - no it's not. A loop that runs for `n` iterations runs in `O(n)` time if the runtime of each iteration is bounded by a constant, but if the per-iteration runtime is not bounded in such a fashion, the loop may run in time much worse than `O(n)`.

Comment: I guess you are right. The answer I eventually came up with after examining outputs for this function that is it O(2^n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instrument your code like this

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
def fib3(n):
    c[n] += 1
    if n < 9980:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-3)

fib3(10000)
print c
```

You'll get a result like this

```
Counter({9979: 223317, 9978: 187427, 9977: 121415, 9980: 121415, 9981: 66012, 9982: 35890, 9983: 19513, 9984: 10609, 9985: 5768, 9986: 3136, 9987: 1705, 9988: 927, 9989: 504, 9990: 274, 9991: 149, 9992: 81, 9993: 44, 9994: 24, 9995: 13, 9996: 7, 9997: 4, 9998: 2, 9999: 1, 10000: 1})
```

Ignoring the values for keys less than 9980, you can already see that the number of calls approximately doubles for each `n` as `n` decreases

So you can estimate that the complexity as O(2<sup>n</sup>)   (It's actually about **O(1.839<sup>n</sup>))**

If you wish to calculate the exact number of calls, you should try writing a recursive function, say `fib3_count(n)` that returns the number of calls required to calculate `fib3(n)`

**EDIT:**

Calculating the big-O complexity can be done by solving this equation

```
 x**3 - x**2 - x**1 - 1 == 0
```

Where the complexity is O(x<sup>n</sup>)

The 3 roots to the equation are

```
x1 = 1.8392867552141612
x2 = (-0.41964337760708065+0.6062907292071992j)
x3 = (-0.41964337760708065-0.6062907292071992j)
```

Since x has to be real, we are left with: O(1.8392867552141612<sup>n</sup>)

Comment: I got the same answer and conclusion. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: It has 3 recursive calls, which makes it O(3^n)

Comment: @evhen14, it's actually a little less than O(2**n). Easy to see empirically here. Certainly not O(3**n).

Comment: @gnibbler it pure coincidence that `O(2^n)` matches the answer. On each recursive call it has 3 sub calls, so it should be O(3^n).

Comment: @evhen14 O(2^n) is an _overestimate_. Your own answer shows that O(3^n) grows much too fast

Comment: @user2417731, it's a bit less than 2**n, see the update to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This runs in exponential time. It's straightforward to show that `fib3(i)` runs quicker than `fib3(k)` if `i < k`, since computing `fib3(k)` will involve computing `fib3(i)`, possibly many times. Computing `fib3(n+3)` requires computing `fib3(n+2)`, `fib3(n+1)`, and `fib3(n)`; thus, it takes at least 3 times as long as computing `fib3(n)`. By induction, you can show that `fib3(n)` takes at least `O(3^(n/3))` time to compute. A more sophisticated analysis could give an asymptotically exact bound.

Comment: when you compute O-notation, constant factors should be eliminated. So your answer should be O(3^n) not O(3^(n/3))

Comment: @evhen14: That is not a constant factor. `3^n` is not proportional to `3^(n/3)`; the ratio between those functions is `3^(2n/3)`.

Comment: Once you get n>15, it's clear it's converging around O(1.839**n). I'll be interested to see how that number is derived

Answer (score 0):

On each recursive call you do 3 additional calls. It's very similar to the binary tree, but there they have 2 children and the total number of children in full binary tree is pow(2, n).

Here you have 3 diversions of flow, which makes it `O(3^n)`

**EDIT:**

Here is some code:

```
import math
class F:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0

    def fib3(self, n):
        self.c += 1
        if n < 3:
            return 1
        else:
            return self.fib3(n-1) + self.fib3(n-2) + self.fib3(n-3)

f = F()
f.fib3(20)
print f.c
```

the output will be:

128287

`print math.pow(3, 20)` evaluates to 3486784401. Which is overestimate, but it's dictated by the fact that fib3 can decreases by 3 instead of 1.

if you run the following code with fib3 always called on n-1 you will get `O(3^n)`

```
import math
class F:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0

    def fib3(self, n):

        if n < 1:
            return 1
        else:
            self.c += 1
            return self.fib3(n-1) + self.fib3(n-1) + self.fib3(n-1)

f = F()
f.fib3(10)
print f.c
```

Actually you will get `O((3^n) / 2)`, but two here is a factor, so it will be just `O(3^n)`

Comment: This would only be correct if the depth of all paths through the recursive call tree was `n`. However, many paths are shorter than `n`, some as short as about `n/3`. You can see a similar effect in the runtime of the naive recursive method of computing the fibonacci sequence; the runtime of that is `O(phi^n)`, where phi is the golden ratio, despite all non-leaf calls producing 2 recursive calls.

Comment: You might be right in terms of calculations, but it's not O notation. O notation does not include factors. Is, like binary search. You can find a value on the first iteration, but the worst case will be log n. So it makes it not O(log n / 2) but O(log n)

Comment: `3^n` and `3^(n/3)` do not differ by a constant factor. They differ by an exponential factor, `3^(2n/3)`. Big-O notation does not drop such factors.

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe you are right, but how did you come up with the fact that it's n/3. It looks rather n-3.

Comment: That's explained in my answer. It's a lower bound; the exact asymptotic runtime is higher.

Comment: @user2357112 It's a bit wrong. If you see my edited version and run `math.pow(3, 20/3)` for  O(3^(n/3)) it will give you 729 which is wrong (729 < 128287).